# Working of Row Level Security on Apache Superset

Tags: business-intelligence, apache-superset, row-level-security

I am not clear about the working of Row Level Security on Apache Superset. As we know it will filter the data and return the out put. My doubt is

The filter is applying to the SQL query itself to fetch the data from database?

Or the data set will load all the data based on the inline query, then row level filter will apply on that result set?

Any reference will be greatly appreciated...